# DataFrame Pandas condition over a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, conditional-statements

Dear fellows I´ve difficulties by performing a condition over a column in my DataFrame, i want to iterate over the column and extract only the values that starts with the number 6, the values from that column are floats.
The columns is called "Vendor".

[This is my Dataframe, and I want to sum the values from the column "Amount in loc.curr.2" only for the values from column "Vendor" starts with 6.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3y8E8.png) 
[This is what I´ve been traying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpbyI.png)
[Also this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uv28M.png)

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
idx = df_spend['Vendor'].apply(lambda x: str(x).startswith('6'))
```

This should create a Boolean pandas.Series that you can use as an index.

```
summed_col=df_spend.loc[idx,"Amount in loc.curr.2"].apply(sum)
```

summed_col contains the sum of the column

Definitely take a look at the pandas documentation for the apply function: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

Hope this works! :)